# My program won't take input after first Iteration

Tags: c++, input

I'm new to Coding and C++ is my first language,
so I made this program which ciphers and deciphers the text after taking text(string) input from user, I want this program to be able to use multiple times in 1 run, so I made this recursive loop,
program runs fine in first iteration , but in 2nd iteration it just skips the text input and moves forward

```
void cipherMain()
{
    std::string text;
    int selectOpt;

    std::cout << "Enter Text" << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, text);
    // std::cin >> text;

    std::cout << "1.Cipher the text\n2.Decipher the text\n";
    std::cout << "Select your option: ";
    std::cin >> selectOpt;

    std::string cipheredText;
    std::string deCipheredText;

    switch (selectOpt)
    {
    case 1:
        cipheredText = cipher(text);
        std::cout << "Ciphered text is:\n\"" << cipheredText << "\"\n";
        system("pause");
        break;

    case 2:
        deCipheredText = dCipher(text);
        std::cout << "Deciphered text is:\n\"" << deCipheredText << "\"\n";
        system("pause");
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Invalid Input" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    char restart;
    std::cout << "Enter 'y' to restart the program or 'n' to exit the program\n";
    std::cin >> restart;
    
    if(restart=='y')
    {
        system("cls");
        cipherMain();
    }
    else
    {
        system("exit");
    }
    
}
```

What I tried:
I replaced `getline(std::cin,text)` with `std::cin >> text;`
this works, but I want my program to take whole line instead of just taking 1 word in input.
I want to get my `getline(std::cin,text)` working

[this is 1st iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgv8C.png)

[this is my 2nd iteration where text input is ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G0In.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste text, instead of providing images of text.

Comment: This is a slightly obscure case of [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction). (It happens "across" function calls, which makes it difficult to spot.)

Comment: Side notes: don't recurse - use a loop, and don't use `system("exit")` - use `return;`.

Comment: those are images when i ran my program, it is just to show how my 2nd iteration is ignoring input and moving forward.

Comment: @molbdnilo can i know reasons for why not to use recursion and `system("exit")`

Comment: A loop is more suitable (it would make your bug more visible, for one), and why would you call an external platform-dependent command when you can just return from the function? (I can't imagine any situation at all where `system("exit")` is appropriate.)

Comment: @molbdnilo oh thanks, similarly is there any alternative for `system("cls")` 
it clears the console screen

Comment: Not clearing the screen is the best approach.

Comment: If you recurse, you are also filling the stack up,  which can be avoided with the loop that @molbdnilo suggested?

Comment: yes, it did solve my question, 
thanks to @molbdnilo , forgot to say it earlier that it solved it